# ISO 8601 not retaining timezone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

i am using the timeago Jquery plugin to output strings like "5 mins ago" etc.

The plugin uses ISO 8601 date format.

I have a Date object which looks like this in console:

```
Sat Jun 15 2013 07:16:23 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

To convert it into ISO 8601 I do this:

```
date = date.toISOString();
```

Now it looks like this in the console:

```
2013-06-15T01:46:23Z
```

Apparently, the time zone has been set to UTC ( Z stand for UTC ). 
This messes up with timeago plugin as everything is now in UTC, not in the local timezone.

I tried this:

```
Date.prototype.toISOStringfix = function() {
    function pad(n) { return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n }
    return this.getUTCFullYear() + '-'
        + pad(this.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '-'
        + pad(this.getUTCDate()) + 'T'
        + pad(this.getUTCHours()) + ':'
        + pad(this.getUTCMinutes()) + ':'
        + pad(this.getUTCSeconds()) + 'Z';
};
```

However, I get the same result.

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: Please explain how "This messes up with `timeago` plugin". What results are you getting and how do those differ from your expectations. Since `timeago` is presumably calculating relative times, if all its times are in UTC the results should be correct.

Comment: Just because you see a local time (India Standard Time) when you evaluate a `Date` object to a string, does not mean that is actually what you have in the `Date` object.  Internally, all javascript `Date` objects are tracked as an integer number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 **UTC**.